# Trying to change the orientation of my type

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typesetting

I have Adobe Design Premium CS4 with Illustrator CS4.  For some reason, my type is now vertical instead of horizontal when using Illustrator.  There was another question along the same line as this a couple of years ago - I followed all the suggestions, but nothing has changed. The letters are not running vertically, they are running from bottom to top at a 90 degree angle from what they should be doing - actually, my letters are going bottom to top, not top to bottom, and they are facing the opposite direction.

Help!  How can I get them to go horizontally across the page?!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at the 'Character Rotation' field in the 'Character' panel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). If that won't work, this object may actually be rotated, but using normal text. Hit <kbd>R</kbd> then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and rotate, see what happens.

[image: Editing in progressEditing in progress]

Comment: That does work to finally be able to get my type running horizontally!  Thank you!  However, when I open Illustrator and create a text box and start typing, it still types bottom to top.  How can I get the orientation to permanently go back to horizontal?  I know I did something to change the orientation; I just don't know what it was!

Comment: Any settings you do with NO document open becomes a permanent setting and will affect all future documents. Open AI but close all documents, make whatever settings you need, then close AI. This will make those settings permanent.

Comment: I'm confused.....the "Character rotation" is grayed out when there isn't a document open, so I can't make any changes.  It really doesn't seem to matter, because the rotation is set to 0 anyway......but when I open a new document, they type is style vertical.

Comment: @PamelaKing open a document and without selecting any text change the character rotation value. That way the next text you create will be correct.